# How to write this window.history.go(-historyCount) correct

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a piece of code that I am writing, I need the user to go back in its history depending on the number of products there are in a shopping cart.

So I wrote this code:

```
var productCount = $('.rdsubs-cart-name').length;
var historyCount = productCount + 1;
console.log(historyCount);
$("a.btn-continue").click(function() {
  window.history.go(-historyCount);
});
```

But as I expected this part is written wrong.
`window.history.go(-historyCount);`

I don't know the naming so it is really difficult for me to find something about it in Google. So I was hoping one of you could point me in the right direction!

Thanks!

**Some More Info:**

When there are 4 products in the cart and the user removes 1 product then it reloads the page. So when the user removes all 4 products it has also reloaded the page 4 times. So if the user clicks on continue shopping then it needs to go back into the history 5 pages. Otherwise, there would be an endless loop of reloading the shopping cart.

When I write `window.history.go(-5);` it works but when I write `window.history.go(-historyCount);` nothing happens.

**The code was actually correctly written!**
The culprit was my browser. After opening another browser and going to the same page everything worked as expected. I am thankful for everyone helping out!

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but I don't immediately notice anything "wrong" with that code. Can you clarify what you're expecting to happen, in contrast to what actually *is* happening?

Comment: @TylerRoper When clicked nothing is happening and I don't get an error in the console. When I change `historyCount` for a number it works. I will add more info in the question.

Comment: What if you `console.log(historyCount)` in your click event? Is it what you expect?

Comment: @TylerRoper Yes, I already have that. But it is not in the code above I will add it there as well. But the console log shows the correct number only when clicking the button nothing happens.

Comment: [I've copied + pasted your code into JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3o9125n8/) and it works perfectly. As you can tell, there is simply not enough information in your question for us to give you a definite answer. Your issue seems unrelated to the code you've included.

Comment: @TylerRoper Thank you for creating the fiddle. When I click on the button in the fiddle also nothing is happening is it reacting differently at your end?

Comment: On my end, clicking the button does in fact send me back 5 pages.

Comment: @TylerRoper I found the culprit. It was my browser. Loaded your fiddle and the page that I was working on with a different browser and now everything works as expected. Thank you very much for helping me out!

Comment: Glad you got it working. You need to provide and accept an answer or delete your post to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was actually correctly written! The culprit was my browser. After opening another browser and going to the same page everything worked as expected. I am thankful for everyone helping out!

Answer (score 1):

I think one mistake that could be happening is that *productCount* has changed since the event has been defined, but since you're retrieving the value outside the event, you're not using the latest value and therefore are seeing an unexpected result.

Move the retrieval of *productCount* into the event function and see if that fixes whatever issue you're experiencing.

```
$("a.btn-continue").click(function() {
  var productCount = $('.rdsubs-cart-name').length;
  var historyCount = productCount + 1;
  window.history.go(-historyCount);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I tried it and it goes exactly the same it shows up fine in the console log but nothing happens.